# eclipse find/replace regex - finding first appearance of a character

Tags: regex, eclipse

im working with Eclipse IDE

im trying to replace all "i" character first appearance on each line,  with "I"

example:

```
today is a very nice day
```

should become:

```
today Is a very nice day
```

I tried doing

```
find: \i[1] replace with: I
```

many thanks

Comment: Find `i` and replace with `I`.Do not use `replaceall` button but use `replace`.You just dont need `global` or `g` flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
^([^i]*)i
```

Replacement string:

```
\1I
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `()` Capturing group.
- `[^i]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `i` zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

> replace all "i" character first appearance on each line, with "I"

You can try with *Negative Lookahead* to find the first "i" character

Find :

```
             (?!=i)i(.*$)
 Not i ---------^^   ^^---------Rest characters in a capturing group
```

Replace with:

```
I\1
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM3pR6/1)